# How can I use sympy to find the error in approximation of a definite integral?

Tags: python, sympy

Our assignment is to use sympy to evaluate the exact definite integral of a function and then compare it with the approximation of the definite integral obtained from another python function we wrote. With simple polynomial functions my code works fine, but with a complicated sine function it keeps either breaking or returning nan.

```
from numpy import *
def simpson(f,a,b,n):
  if n<=0 or n%2!=0:
    print('Error: the number of subintervals must be a positive even number')
    return float('NaN')
  h = float(b - a) / float(n)
  x = arange(a,b+h,h)
  fx = f(x)
  fx[1:n:2] *= 4.0
  fx[2:n:2] *= 2.0
  return (h/3.)*sum(fx)
```

this is in one file (simpandtrap) and gives the approximation for the definite integral of f from a to b using a simpson's rule approximation with n subintervals

```
from pylab import *

def s(x):
  return x*sin(3./(x+(x==0)))
```

This is the function giving me trouble, in a file called assignment8functions

```
import assignment8functions as a
import SimpAndTrap as st
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
Exact_int_q = sp.integrate(a.q(x),(x,0,2)).evalf(25)
Exact_int_s = sp.integrate(x*sp.sin(3./(x)),(x,0,2)).evalf(25)
```

q(x) is another function we're supposed to use that everything works fine for - it's just a polynomial. When I try to do the integration the same way it breaks, so I had to put the function for s(x) directly into the call instead of importing the one from the other file

```
n = a.array([10,100,1000,10000,10000,1000000])
s_error_simp_array = a.zeros(6)
for i in a.arange(6):
  s_error_simp_array[i] = abs(Exact_int_s - st.simpson(a.s,0,2,n[i])
```

here I try to find the error in the approximation. the problem is first of all that Exact_int_s is apparently -4.5*Si(zoo) + 8.16827746848576, and I have no idea what that's supposed to mean, and also that the simpson function always returns nan.

I know it's a lot of words and code, but does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the answer `-4.5*Si(zoo)+ 8.---` just start the integration at a small positive number, e.g.:

```
x = sp.Symbol('x')
print sp.integrate( x * sin(3./x), (x, 0.000001, 2) )
```

and you'll get an answer like `1.0996940...`

You can justify this because `|s(x)| <= x` for small `x`, so the interval `[0, epsilon]` can't contribute that much.

Btw - your simpson implemention seems to check out.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same thing when calling the simpson rule function and that fixed the nan problem too